# How do I map a point type in CakePHP 3.3?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, point, custom-type

I tried to follow the instructions in the documentation to implement a custom type 'point,' but I am having trouble. I added file: vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Point.php with this code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Database;
// Our value object is immutable.
class Point {
    protected $_lat;
    protected $_long;
    // Factory method.
    public static function parse($value) {
        // Parse the data from MySQL.
        return new static($value[0], $value[1]);
    }
    public function __construct($lat, $long) {
        $this->_lat = $lat;
        $this->_long = $long;
    }
    public function lat( {
        return $this->_lat;
    }
    public function long() {
        return $this->_long;
    }
}
?>
```

Then I created file: vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type/PointType.php with code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Type;

use App\Database\Point;
use Cake\Database\Expression\FunctionExpression;
use Cake\Database\Type as BaseType;
use Cake\Database\Type\ExpressionTypeInterface;

class PointType extends BaseType implements ExpressionTypeInterface {
    public function toPHP($value, Driver $d) {
        return Point::parse($value);
    }
    public function marshal($value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = explode(',', $value);
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return new Point($value[0], $value[1]);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function toExpression($value) {
        if ($value instanceof Point) {
            return new FunctionExpression(
                'POINT',
                $value->lat(),
                $value->long()
            );
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return new FunctionExpression('POINT', $value[0], $value[1]);
        }
    // Handle other cases.
    }
}
?>
```

Then I added this line to config/bootstrap.php:

```
Type::map('point', 'App\Database\Type\PointType');
```

and this line to src/Model/Table/ForecastsTable.php:

```
use Cake\Database\Schema\Table as Schema;

protected function _initializeSchema(Schema $schema) {
    $schema->columnType('location', 'point');
    return $schema;
}
```

where location is the name of the column in my MySQL table Forecasts which holds POINT type geo values with a spatial index.
If I access the website from any page, I get this Fatal Error twice:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Database\Type\PointType' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\forecast_clash\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Type.php
>   on line 106

Here is the function called in Type.php with line 106 *'d

```
public static function build($name) {
if (isset(static::$_builtTypes[$name])) {
    return static::$_builtTypes[$name];
}
if (!isset(static::$_types[$name])) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unknown type "%s"', $name));
}
if (is_string(static::$_types[$name])) {
   **return static::$_builtTypes[$name] = new static::$_types[$name]($name);**
}

return static::$_builtTypes[$name] = static::$_types[$name];
}
```

Things I have tried:
Moving the content of PointType.php to the bottom of Type.php which got me this error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of App\Database\Type\PointType::toPHP() must
>   be compatible with Cake\Database\TypeInterface::toPHP($value,
>   Cake\Database\Driver $driver) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\forecast_clash\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Type.php
>   on line 307

so I changed that back and edited the $_builtTypes function in Type.php to:

```
protected static $_builtTypes = ['point' => 'Cake\Database\Type\PointType',];
```

which cleared all the fatal errors, but seemed like I was bypassing things I shouldn't and I ran into a bunch of new errors when trying to access my Forecasts table in my DB.

I am new to CakePHP and am really struggling to decipher the errors and figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're not supposed to put files in the `vendors` folder or edit the contents in there, that's the place for [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org/) managed dependencies. Have another look at [**the docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html), the `src` folder mentioned  there is the `src` folder in your application root.

Comment: But none of the folders or files mentioned in this part of the docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#mapping-custom-datatypes-to-sql-expressions are in my app/src folder, only in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/. Do I need to create a Database folder in my app/src?

Comment: That's what you need to do, yes, you create a folder structure matching the namespace (where `src` = `App` so to speak) - that's tied to composer/PSR autoloading, you may want to study that topic a little,  it plays an important role for most PHP code nowadays.

Comment: I will definitely look more into it.  I followed your instructions and that did indeed clear the errors I had been getting, but now I'm getting the error I got when I tried moving the code from PointType into Type:
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Database\Type\PointType::toPHP() must be compatible with Cake\Database\TypeInterface::toPHP($value, Cake\Database\Driver $driver) in C:\xampp\htdocs\forecast_clash\src\Database\Type\PointType.php on line 9

Comment: I hate to be that "_that's xyz basics_" guy, but well, that's PHP OOP/Namepsace basics, the signature in the extending class doesn't match the signature in the extended class. The example in the docs seems to be missing a `use` statement for the `Driver` reference, ie an `use Cake\Database\Driver;`

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! I am not just new to Cake but also MVC and OOP, so it is hard for me to know what problem stems from what area, but I am learning on a deadline.  I appreciate you taking the time to point me towards what I need to learn, but also fixing this instance of my problems. I am ALSO new to anything but search StackOverflow, so I don't know how to thank you or give you credit, but I would be glad to do it!

Comment: @Lightbringer, How did you do to read data ? toPHP method give me blob data from MySQL. And Point::parse fail ...

Comment: @TeChn4K, I read through the docs step by step and given the advice from this post, I was able to save the data, but never able to read it.  Got the same data as you and couldn't even hire someone to fix it for me. In the end, I just figured out a different method for my app that didn't require spatial indexing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering if this is doable with CakePHP 4.x (yes, POINT() is still unsupported natively!), it is.

1. Create a `Point` and `PointType` class [as described in the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#mapping-custom-datatypes-to-sql-expressions)
2. In your bootstrap.php file or elsewhere, call `Type::setMap()` to register the new type and the associated class
3. In your query, call setDefaults() to set the new type correctly

**Here is a working example**

```
<?php

use App\Domain\Base\Point;
use App\Domain\Base\PointType;
use Cake\Database\Connection;
use Cake\Database\Type;

$bootstrap = include __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

Type::setMap(array_merge(Type::getMap(), ['point' => '\App\Domain\Base\PointType']));

$db = new Connection($bootstrap['db']);
$sql = $db->newQuery();
$sql->getTypeMap()->setDefaults(['location' => 'point']);
$sql->insert(['location'])->into('address')->values(['location' => new Point(40.71727401, -74.00898606)]);
$sql->execute();
```

p.s. Make sure to adjust the namespace to your actual namespace (most likely `App\Database\Type`).